# can not import image from src folder after deploying to heroku from build folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, multer

i saved my all image in src folder of react and when user upload image i save this image in this folder but when i run build command for deploy app to heroku app can't find image from src and also user can upload image and this image save in src folder but i can't use it because of when i create build folder the image is not in src folder and when i try to save image in build folder this is also not working for me

how i import image

```
         <img src={require(`./../../photo/${user.photo}`)} alt="UserPhoto" className="imgsrc" ></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral/short lived. Meaning, any files your users upload will disappear after you redeploy your app. You can't rely on Heroku's filesystem to store user files that need to persist for a longer time.

To store images uploaded by your users, you can look at 3rd party storage solutions such as Cloudinary or AWS S3.